# Database in VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net-2010

I am almost beginner to VB.net and I was willing to design a software on school management. Guys please help me in database i.e. how to link database to my project, how to search for data in it, how to add data, how to delete data etc. Please guys help me out.
(Database -:MS Access)
(Environment -:Visual Studio 2010)

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: No one can help you like this. Please share your problem and efforts you have done to solve only then one of us can try to resolve your issue.

Comment: @RajanMishra 
Ok
My project starts with a loading form. I want that at the time of loading in background &quot;checks whether there is any name of school in attached database or not.&quot; If no school name found in database it means user is starting the s/w for the first time so after loading, college details form appears but if school name is found then user moves to login page after loading.
My problem is in double quotes above.
Database name-:school_mngmnt
Particular table-:school_details
Particular field-:school_name